# set timeout with jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery

I have some ajax code that works great. Upon button click it calls the `doAjax` function every 2 secs until it receives a message from the server (success being the text `Initializing...please wait`).

What I want to add is a timeout in case the server is down or whatever. So I added the timeout and error function:

```
$(document).on("click", ".play", function() {
function doAjax(){
 $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'Initializing...please wait')
        {
            $('#quote p').html(data).css({'border': '1px solid', 'margin': '10px 0px'});
            setTimeout(doAjax, 2000);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, strError) {
        if(strError == 'timeout')
        {
          $('#quote p').html("Oops! Not found...").css({'border': '1px solid'});
        }
    },
    timeout: 8000
 });
}
doAjax();
});
```

The code still works but I never see a timeout happen after the 8 seconds. I tried removing the recursion but still have the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess, try first removing the recursion from your ajax call, and see if your timeout is working as required.

Also, why do you have your function definition inside your function call? You should make your function defined outside, the on-click call, and then call it from within.

Comment: A very reasonable question. Except for some reason I cannot get anything to work unless the doAjax function is in the click handler. I tried removing recursion but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hi again. Your function should work outside the on-click call. I have done it a million times, and should not be a problem. Fix this problem as well. Now, for the timeout, try to see if the callback is even made, with code like this `error: function(){alert ("error")}`

Comment: added the alert, it doesn't seem to get to the error function

Comment: OK, this is good. Now, your url is index.php (in the line `url: index.php`). I am not sure why are you making your ajax call to index.php, because typically this is the script that runs and gets back to you. So, just for the sake of debuging, make a call to a new file, call it ajaxHandler.php and in that file, make sure you have only one line of code,` <?php sleep(10); ?>` This will make your code sleep for 10 seconds. Now with our timeout set to 8000 (ie. 8 seconds) we should probably get somewhere.

Comment: Wahab sent me on the right track. The way my code is setup with the recursion I will never get to the error code. The timeout works fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in ajaxSetup method:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     timeout: 10000,
})
```